# vim doesnt recognize html in string in filetype php. same thing with php code in filetype html

Tags: syntax-highlighting, indentation, filetype-html, filetype-php

Ive had no luck solving these issues for quite a while now.

## Problem1

When writing HTML inside a string in a file with `filetype=php`, the HTML is not recognized (*i.e.*, it has no highlighting or indent).

[image: problem1]

### What I've tried to solve this problem

1. I found [this plugin](https://github.com/Shougo/context_filetype.vim/blob/master/doc/context_filetype.txt) (this plugin uses pattern matching to determine if text is in a different language), but I didn't have any luck.

   I tried testing this plugin by writing some javascript and CSS in a buffer with `filetype=html`, and as you can see in the second picture, javascript and CSS are highlighted and correctly indented. I am not actually sure if this was caused by the plugin. Nonetheless php is not correctly highlighted. Highlighting for these languages may have been working already.
2. As you can see in the picture above, `php_htmlInStrings` is set to `1`; however, this doesn't make a difference. I am using additional syntax highlighting for php; perhaps that is causing a conflict?

## Problem2

When writing php code in a buffer with `filetype=html`, valid php code within the opening(`<?php`) and closing(`?>`) tags are not highlighted or indented.

As you can see, for some reason vim highlights some keywords like `class` and `for` but those are the only two words I've found that get recognized. `class` and `for` do not get highlighted outside of the php tags, which leads me to believe that vim is aware that it is php code within the tags, but for some reason is only able to highlight those two words.

See this screenshot:

[image: problem2]

### More I've tried

> As you can see in picture above `php_htmlInStrings` is set to `1`
> however this doesnt make a difference. I am using additional syntax
> highlighting php.vim, maybe conflicting configs?

I couldn't help but think this was my php additional syntax plugin conflicting with the settings or something, so I removed the plugin and tried writing html in a php file.

Look at this picture below: obviously the highlighting looks different as expected, but when `php_htmlInStrings` is set to `1`, you can clearly see that vim *recognized* the html tags, but failed to indent them properly. Weird? Anyway so the additional syntax plugin that I am using doesn't seem to be contributing to this issue.

[image]

## Possible <s>Solution</s> workaround

Write a function to change `filetype` to one desired and bind it to a key so I can manually switch between filetypes while editing. This should be a last resort, since I really don't want to do this.

Comment: `so i can manually switch between filetypes while editing?` Changing filetype is as easy as `:setf foobar`. GVim even has a dropdown menu for that.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This Question currently has 2 questions entangled—we prefer to stick to 1 questions per Question where possible, and here I think it might be, so please consider splitting one of them into a separate Q.

Comment: I've removed comments about gvim/IDEs—let's use [chat] instead of [comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for things like that.